# How to run multiple commands in one batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I want to run multiple commands in one batch file.

I tried the &, &&, start, /wait, call, :begin and goto begin commands but no luck.

Here are my commands:

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

sc config remoteregistry start= auto 

sc start remoteregistry 

sc config Schedule start=auto 

sc start Schedule 

sc stop McAfeeFramework

sc configure McAfeeFramework startup= disabled

sc stop  McShield

sc configure  McShield startup= disabled

sc stop McTaskManager 

sc configure McTaskManager startup= disabled

netsh advfirewall set AllProfiles state off 

sc stop MpsSvc

sc config MpsSvc start= disabled
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean - aren't those multiple commands? Do you mean at the same time?

Comment: Yes cmd doesn't want to run them all when you double click it or run it as admin but it only runs the first one.

Comment: Running the first line only? See `cmd /?`. Take a special look to `/k` versus `/c`

Comment: Thanks I managed I just put start only in the beginning of each parallel command :)

Comment: I suggest that @Stephan convert its comment into an answer and the OP select it, so the rest of us know that this question was already solved...

Answer (score 2):

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /k <command>
```

starts a new cmd context where  is executed, but `/k` keeps that new context open. You want to close it after executing , so further commands from the original context can be executed. Use `/c` instead of `/k` to do so.

described in `cmd /?`

Comment: Thanks but I managed but it is still good to know other things.

Answer (score 0):

Well, batch scripts already do it by default, but i guess that your usage of /K on cmd.exe it was unnecessary and harmful, and A / C could have done the job even though, remembering, it is not necessary.

**File1.bat***

```
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c %windir%\System32\reg.exe ADD HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /t REG_DWORD /d 0 /f

sc config remoteregistry start= auto 

sc start remoteregistry 

sc config Schedule start=auto 

sc start Schedule 

sc stop McAfeeFramework

sc configure McAfeeFramework startup= disabled

sc stop  McShield

sc configure  McShield startup= disabled

sc stop McTaskManager 

sc configure McTaskManager startup= disabled

netsh advfirewall set AllProfiles state off 

sc stop MpsSvc

sc config MpsSvc start= disabled
```