# How to run multiple commands (each from a new terminal) from a batch file in Windows

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been using Ubuntu all my life, but today I've been given a different machine installed with `Windows 10`. I've an `Angular` project and I want to do the following things. All these in a separate terminal:

1. Navigate into project folder and run `code .` so that I can see the code on Visual studio.
2. Navigate into project folder and run `ng serve` to launch my application and keep it running.
3. Navigate into project folder and run `node server.js` to start backend server and keep it running.

   this is very painful as the project location is-

`C:\Users\tanzeel\Downloads\social-coder`

Navigating again and again with a new terminal is what wasting my time. I decided to write a `batch` file so that I can do all at once with one single click. This is what my `starter.bat` file contains:

```
cd C:\Users\tanzeel\Downloads\social-coder\application 2>nul && call npm.cmd start
node C:\Users\tanzeel\Downloads\social-coder\server\server.js
code C:\Users\tanzeel\Downloads\social-coder
```

All of the above 3 commands works perfectly If I manually copy-paste them in separate terminals. But when I try to run them from batch file the problem is only first command is executed.I don't know other two are simply ignored or what. I'm coming from:

1. [How to run multiple commands in a batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34922908/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-a-batch-file)
2. [How to run multiple commands in one batch file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32733567/how-to-run-multiple-commands-in-one-batch-file)

I admit that I'm a newbie and there are gaps in my knowledge. Please correct me.

Comment: Use `cd /D` instead of `cd` in order to also switch the drive if necessary...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use e.g. `START` to spawn new processes, otherwise the currently running program will just block until it's finished. It looks to me that this is what you want:

```
@ECHO OFF
CD C:\Users\tanzeel\Downloads\social-coder
START code .
CD application
START npm start
CD ..\server
START node server.js
EXIT
```

Comment: Ok I'll try this solution. But I've already tried `CALL`, `PUSHD` and `START "" /WAIT`. Maybe my implementation was wrong. So I'll try yours. Give me 2 mins please.

Comment: @Tanzeel: take your time. a good resource for all things windows shell is ss64, here for example [the page on the `START` command](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).

Comment: This solution worked like a magic wand. But there is one tiny problem. 1) I'm getting one extra terminal with `C:\Users\tanzeel\Downloads\social-coder>` Can you fix this please :-)

Comment: @Tanzeel: looks like this is the window of the batch script itself. this can be closed down with the `EXIT` command. also, if you're just running the script via a link on the desktop, and not via the shell, then the use `PUSHD`/`POPD` is not really needed.

Comment: I'm still getting and extra terminal. But leave it. I'll deal with it. That's not a big issue. You've already solved my main problem. thanks :-)